# How to map Django order_with_respect_to to Django Rest Framework

Tags: django, rest, model, django-rest-framework

I'm trying to store a user-modifyable ordering in my Django db and read/write it via Django Rest Framework.

I found the awesome `order_with_respect_to` in Django to model this in Django itself. Here's the example from Rest Framework documentation modified to show this feature:

```
class Album(models.Model):
    album_name = models.CharField(max_length=100)

class Track(models.Model):
    album = models.ForeignKey(Album, related_name='tracks')

    class Meta:
        order_with_respect_to = 'album'
```

This stores the ordering into an `_order` field in the backend and allows to read/write the Track order on the Album object:

```
>>> album = Album.objects.get(id=1)
>>> album.get_track_order()
[3604L, 3605L, 3606L, 3608L, 3607L]
>>> album.set_track_order([3607L, 3606L, 3605L, 3608L, 3604L]
```

**What's an elegant way to make "track_order" accessible (read/write) in the rest interface of Album?**

Essentially I'm looking for a `ModelGetterSetterMethodField` (a `ModelField` can access model attributes, but not via get/set functions) or a `RelatedOrderingField` that understand the Django `order_with_respect_to` pattern and used the associated functions to read/write the object.

So far I tried using a `SerializerMethodField` (works for reading, fails for writing: `SerializerMethodFields` are read-only) and making a custom `RelatedOrderingField` (worked out well for reading (returning `obj.get_track_order()` in `to_representation()` function), failed for writing because in `to_internal_value()` function I don't have access to the object, so I wouldn't know how to call `"obj.set_track_order (data)"`.